# Obtaining map service url from within Server Object Extension (.NET)?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, server-object-extension

I'm having trouble figuring out how to obtain the full url to the map service a Server Object Extension is running on top of. I bascially want:

```
IMapServer4 mapServer = (IMapServer4)serverObjectHelper.ServerObject;
string fullUrl = mapServer.url
```

Which would yield: http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why do you need the full url?

Comment: I felt that the syntax for the dynamicLayers property inside of an export map request was too verbose.  Specifically, I'm referring to using a uniqueValueRenderer JSON object.  Instead of using symbol1 -> value1, symbol1 -> value2, symbol1 -> value3 - I wanted symbol1 -> [value1, value2, value3].  It turned out that the size of the dynamicLayers object was breaking a portion of the JavaScript API when running from PhoneGap.  The Server Object Extension basically supported this more concise JSON syntax, "re-hydrated" into the verbose form, and forwarded back the image response.

Answer (score 2):

Here's code that returns the msd path.  I don't know of a way to get the original url.  (Remember, one or more web adaptors may be used for a service, each with a different hostname).  The path to the msd could be parsed and used to construct the portions of the url containing the folder and mapservice name.

For testing I find it helpful to also know the processID, which makes it easier to attach a debugger.

```
private byte[] RootResHandler(NameValueCollection boundVariables, string outputFormat, 
    string requestProperties, out string responseProperties)
{
    responseProperties = null;

    JsonObject result = new JsonObject();            
    var id = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
    result.AddString("Machine", Environment.MachineName);
    result.AddString("ProcessID", id.ToString());
    var svrInit = m_serverObjectHelper.ServerObject as IMapServerInit2;
    if (svrInit != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(svrInit.FilePath))
            result.AddString("filepath", svrInit.FilePath);
        else
            result.AddString("filepath", "null filepath");
    }
    else
        result.AddString("filepath", "no svrInit");
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result.ToJson());
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! This is helpful and thats a good point regarding the use of different web adaptors. With limited time left for development, I simply had the client app send the url with the request.  Thanks for your prompt response and I'll post back if I learn anything else on the topic.